# $\frac{1}{(1-x)^{2}}=\sum_{k = 0}^{n}(k + 1)x^k+o(x^{n}).$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives, taylor-expansion

> I would like to show that Taylor expansion of $\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^{2}} $ around $0$ is :
>
> $$\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^{2}}=\sum_{k = 0}^{n}(k + 1)x^k+o(x^{n}).$$

**My Proof:**

note that $$\dfrac{1}{1-x}\underset{x\to 0}=\sum_{k = 0}^{n+1}x^{k}+o(x^{n+1}).$$

Differentiating with respect to $x$ :

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)&\underset{x\to 0}= \frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{k = 0}^{n+1}x^{k}+o(x^{n+1})\right)\\
\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^{2}}&\underset{x\to 0}=\left( \sum_{k = 1}^{n}kx^{k-1} \right)+o((n+1)x^{n})\\
&\text{Shifting the Index } l=k-1\\
\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^{2}}&\underset{x\to 0}=\left( \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1}(k+1)x^{k} \right)+o(x^{n})\\
\end{align}
so the problem i got $n-1$ over $\sum$ not $n$

could someone find my mistake and correct with explanation please

Comment: In the third equation, you should have $k$ from $1$ to $n+1$ and not from $1$ to $n$.

Comment: Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: When you derive a sum of, say, $n+1>2$ terms $x^{0}+x^{1}+\dots+x^{n+1}$, it gives $0+1+\dots+(n+1)x^n=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}kx^{k-1}$ and not $\sum_{k=1}^{n}kx^{k-1}$ as you wrote.

Comment: but here $n+1$ is greater than or equal to $2$ since $n$ can take $0$

Comment: This is not relevant. Let's take a small example: $1+x+x^{2}+x^{3}$ (so $n=2$). The derivative is $1+2x+3x^{2}=\sum_{k=1}^{3}kx^{k-1}$. We have the sum from $k=1$ to $k=n+1=2+1=3$. And for $n=0$ or $n=1$, it is obvious that it works perfectly well.

Comment: yes, could you elaborate this as an answer to my question

Answer (score 1):

As you requested:
$$\frac{1}{1-x}\underset{x\to 0}{=}\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}x^{k}+o(x^{n+1})$$

Differentiating with respect to $x$:
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right) &\underset{x\to 0}{=}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}x^{k}+o(x^{n+1})\right)\\
&\underset{x\to 0}{=}\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x^{k}\right)+\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(o(x^{n+1})\right)
\end{aligned}$$
Here is the line you have to pay attention to. The sum goes from $k=0$ to $k=n+1$, so that you have:
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right) &\underset{x\to 0}{=}\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x^{k}\right)+\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(o(x^{n+1})\right)\\
&\underset{x\to 0}{=}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}kx^{k-1}+o((n+1)x^{n})\\
\end{aligned}$$
where you can see that this sum now goes from $k=1$ (because the derivative of a constant is zero) to $k=n+1$ (because there is no reason that the term $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x^{n+1}\right)$ disappears). Now, by replacing $k-1$ by $l$, the sum goes from $l=0$ to $l=n+1-1=n$ and it gives what you expected:
$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^{2}}\underset{x\to 0}{=}\sum_{l=0}^{n}(l+1)x^{l}+o(x^{n})$$

Comment: still one thing you didn't justify the  switching  between sum and the derivative

Comment: The derivative of a finite sum is the sum of the derivatives since $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(f(x)+g(x)\right)=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}f(x) + \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}g(x)$ is a well-known fact.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the generalized binomial coefficient:
$$
(1-x)^{-2} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{-2}{k} (-x)^k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)x^k
$$
Then the remainder term is $ - \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$. Keep in mind though $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way
using only algebra:

$\begin{array}\\
(1-x)^2\sum_{k = 0}^{n}(k + 1)x^k
&=(1-2x+x^2)\sum_{k = 0}^{n}(k + 1)x^k\\
&=\sum_{k = 0}^{n}(k + 1)x^k(1-2x+x^2)\\
&=\sum_{k = 0}^{n}(k + 1)(x^k-2x^{k+1}+x^{k+2})\\
&=\sum_{k = 0}^{n}(k + 1)x^k
-2\sum_{k = 0}^{n}(k + 1)x^{k+1}
+\sum_{k = 0}^{n}(k + 1)x^{k+2}\\
&=\sum_{k = 0}^{n}(k + 1)x^k
-2\sum_{k = 1}^{n+1}(k)x^{k}
+\sum_{k = 2}^{n+2}(k - 1)x^{k}\\
&=(1+2x+\sum_{k = 2}^{n}(k + 1)x^k)\\
&\quad-2(x+\sum_{k = 2}^{n}(k)x^{k}+(n+1)x^{n+1})\\
&\quad+(\sum_{k = 2}^{n}(k - 1)x^{k}+nx^{n+1}+(n+1)x^{n+2})\\
&=1+2x-2x-2(n+1)x^{n+1}+nx^{n+1}+(n+1)x^{n+2})\\
&\quad+\sum_{k = 2}^{n}x^k((k + 1)-2k+(k - 1))\\
&=1-(n+2)x^{n+1}+(n+1)x^{n+2}\\
\end{array}
$

so
$\sum_{k = 0}^{n}(k + 1)x^k
=\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^{2}}-\frac{(n+2)x^{n+1}-(n+1)x^{n+2}}{(1-x)^{2}}
$
or

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^{2}}
&=\sum_{k = 0}^{n}(k + 1)x^k+\frac{(n+2)x^{n+1}-(n+1)x^{n+2}}{(1-x)^{2}}\\
&=\sum_{k = 0}^{n}(k + 1)x^k+O(x^{n+1})\\
&=\sum_{k = 0}^{n}(k + 1)x^k+o(x^{n})\\
\end{array}
$